# How can i get Html form value in web view iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, webview, forms

I have a web view in my view controller. In my web view there is a html form is load. Now when user input the value of form and press a button which is into view controller. After pressing the button I need those input value. How can I retrieve this value?

I try this way. but How can I get data?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    somec.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/LoginRegistrationForm/")!))
}


@IBAction func getData(_ sender: Any) {
    let inputValue = somec.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.body.innerHTML")
    print(inputValue!)
}
```

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737316/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-which-returns-an-html-string-in-body-using-swi?rq=1

Comment: this question doesn't any right answer

Answer (score 2):

To get value from username input try this:

```
let userNameValue = somec.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById('username').value")
```

for password value:

```
let passwordNameValue = somec.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.getElementById('password').value")
```

keys 'username' and 'password' are html input tag ids.